# Как вывести имена, чтобы они шли по порядку с зависимостью от данных введенных в переменных?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Формат ввода
> В первой строке записана средняя скорость Пети.
>  Во второй
> — Васи. 
> В третьей — Толи.
>
> Формат вывода 
> Имена победителей в порядке занятых мест.

Код корректно выводит сортированные цифры, но я не понимаю как привязать к вводимым и сортируемым цифрам скорости имена, чтобы они на выходе тоже сортировались.
В коде ниже закомментированные попытки присвоить имена значениям. На выходе нет сортировки.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
a,b,c = sorted([a, b, c], reverse = True)
# a = 'Петя'
# b = 'Вася'
# c = 'Толя'
print('1. ' + a)
print('2. ' + b)
print('3. ' + c)
```

Судя по всему, когда я после сортировки пытаюсь определить новое строчное значение переменным сортировка выше просто убивается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С использованием кортежей (tuple):

```
a = (int(input()), "Петя")
b = (int(input()), "Вася")
c = (int(input()), "Толя")
l = sorted([a, b, c], reverse = True)
for x in l:
   print(x[1], x[0])
```

С номерами:

```
for i, x in enumerate(l):
   print(i+1, '. ', x[1], sep='')
```

Comment: Благодарю! +1 метод в капилку знаний. Но:
вывод должен выглядеть следующим образом (порядковый номер, точка, Имя), каждое имя с новой строки<br />

1. Петя<br />
2. Толя<br />
3. Вася<br />

Comment: А что вам мешает изменить вывод на нужный? Используйте цикл for по range или enumerate для получения номера

Comment: Мешает отсутствие достаточных знаний. Второй момент - как говорится - циклы мы еще не проходили, то есть по плану обучения циклы будут только в следующей теме, и, по идее, это задача должна быть выполнена без циклов. А в enumerate нумерция получается вида "1, Имя", а мне нужно в выводе получить "1. Имя"

Comment: Если вам нужно вывести число, точку, и строку, то так и пишете в принте print(i+1, ".", x[0]). Логично, да ведь?

Comment: благодарю за помощь!) Вероятно логично. Может нужно было не досимвольно понимать комментарий выше. Я подставил этот принт в код из ответа и вот ответ командной строки "name 'i' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?"

Comment: А как у вас называется переменная в enumerate? Мне отсюда плохо видно. Вот ее и используйте

Comment: могу я попросить исправить код в Вашем ответе? Так как самому решить не удается, сколько бы не мучал код)

Comment: Добавил..........

Comment: Премного благодарен!!! на синтаксис немного поругался, но в целом все огонь!

Answer (score 2):

В `Python` есть такая структура данных, как словарь: `dictionary`, она содержит элементы вида ключ-значение.
Для того, чтобы получить то, что вы хотите она подходит наилучшим образом, поскольку вы можете указать соответствие между именем и скоростью.

Советую ознакомиться с [документацией](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) по этой структуре данных.

Вот как можно записать код, используя словарь:

```
speeds = {} # dict
speeds['Петя'] = int(input())
speeds['Вася'] = int(input())
speeds['Толя'] = int(input())

sorted_speeds = sorted(speeds.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for name, speed in sorted_speeds:
    print(name, speed)
```

Вывод:

```
3
17
8

Вася 17
Толя 8
Петя 3
```

Comment: благодарю! Тут ситуация как и в предыдущем ответе) Мне не имя со скоростью нужно на выводе, а порядковый номер и Имя

Comment: Не понимаю, что с форматированием комментов тут, не могу обратиться по имени через @

Answer (score 0):

Спустя день раздумья, я нашел правильный код, соответсвующий теме

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
if a > b and a > c:
    print("1. Петя")
elif b > a and b > c:
    print("1. Вася")
elif c > a and c > b:
    print("1. Толя")
if a > b > c or c > b > a:
    print("2. Вася")
elif b > a > c or c > a > b:
    print("2. Петя")
elif a > c > b or b > c > a:
    print("2. Толя")
if a < b < c or a < c < b:
    print("3. Петя")
elif b < a < c or b < c < a:
    print("3. Вася")    
elif c < a < b or c < b < a:
    print("3. Толя")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]